# PDO prepared statement leads to SIGABRT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, malloc

I am doing a straightforward update of a MySQL database using PDO bound parameters. The update succeeds and a print statement placed after the ->execute(); works fine, but when php tries to exit, I get a malloc error and the php process is aborted by its parent process.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
$edit_type = 'Edit';
$employeeID = 1;
$surname = 'Green';
$givenname = 'Frodo';
$degree = 'PhD';
$title = 'Some_Title';
$division = 'Some_Division';
$office_phone = 'number';
$email = 'adress@someplace.foo';
$room = 'abc-123';
$PI_ID = 1;
$confirmDeactivate = 'Do Not Deactivate';


    //  Establish a MySQL Connection

try {
    $cvbrdbh_update = new PDO("mysql:host={$_SERVER['MYSQL_SERVER']};dbname={$_SERVER['MYSQL_DB']}",$_SERVER['MYSQL_USER'],$_SERVER['MYSQL_PASSWORD'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $cvbrdbh_update->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n" ;
    die();
}
$cvbrdbh_update->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$cvbrdbh_update->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if ($employeeID && $edit_type == "Edit") { 
    if (empty($surname)) { 
        print "Warning! The Surname field was empty. Please restart the editing process and be sure to fill in a surname.";
     } else { 
        $person_update_stmt = $cvbrdbh_update->prepare("UPDATE employees, med_division, titles, pi_emp SET Surname=:surname, GivenName=:givenname, Degree=:degree, Office_Phone=:office_phone, Email=:email, Room=:room, Division=:division, Title=:title, med_division.PI_ID=:pi_id1, pi_emp.PI_ID=:pi_id2 WHERE employees.EmployeeID = '$employeeID' AND med_division.EmployeeID = '$employeeID' AND titles.EmployeeID = '$employeeID' AND pi_emp.EmployeeID = '$employeeID'");
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':surname',$surname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':givenname',$givenname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':degree',$degree,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':office_phone',$office_phone,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':room',$room,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':division',$division,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':title',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':pi_id1',$PI_ID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->bindValue(':pi_id2',$PI_ID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $person_update_stmt->execute();
        print "Finished" .  "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

From this, I get a successful database update, it prints "Finished", then the following error message:

> php(12652) malloc: *** error for object 0x116f07438: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> fish: Job 1, 'php database_write_probe.php ' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)

Fish is my shell. My PHP version is:

> PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44) 
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

My MySQL version is:

> Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.27, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Just as a further data point, it appears that the precise trigger is my use of "bindValue". Taking them out and simply inserting the appropriate variables into the "prepare" statement prevents the crash. So I guess that's one possible solution, though one with serious security problems.

Comment: getting that kind of error means your php install has a MAJOR problem.

Comment: I am running OS X 10.8.2, using the built-in PHP install. Is this a known problem for the PHP setup Apple ships?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your PHP install is out of date or some interim (non-release) build? This appears to be v similar to a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51870). See if you can update or uninstall / reinstall PHP.

Comment: Sadly, this is a bog standard Mac OS X 10.8.2 PHP install. I will look into installing an updated version. is 5.3.15 known to be buggy in this way?

Comment: There are certainly updates / upgrades available. You might try one and see if it's any better.